# Store BLOB in Android's SQLite using SQLOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob, inputstream

Is there a way to store a BLOB into Android's SQLite using `SQLOpenHelper`?

My BLOB of type `InputStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support streaming BLOB or CLOB data. You have four options:

- Convert the InputStream to a byte[]. This will only work if you have enough memory (see below).
- Use FileOutputStream or an Android API that supports streaming
- Split the data into small blocks and store then in SQLite
- Use a database that works on Android and supports streaming. I only know the [H2 database](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android). But be aware the Android support for H2 is very new. In that case, you need to use the JDBC API, and you probably want to enable [LOBs in the database](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/SysProperties.html#h2.lobInDatabase), otherwise each large BLOB is stored in a separate file.

To convert an InputStream to a byte array, you could use:

```
public static byte[] readBytesAndClose(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    try {
        int block = 4 * 1024;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(block);
        byte[] buff = new byte[block];
        while (true) {
            int len = in.read(buff, 0, block);
            if (len < 0) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I convert it to a byte[] and then store that in the BLOB?

Comment: Of course you can convert an InputStream to a byte[], but only if the byte array actually fits in memory. Let me add the code for that.